# How many committees of $6$ people can be formed if a committee is to be chosen from $7$ men and $8$ women must contain at least $3$ women and $2$ men?

Tags: combinatorics

> A committee of $6$ people is to be chosen from a group consisting of $7$ men and $8$ women. If the committee must consist of at least $3$ women and at least $2$ men, how many different committees are possible?

The answer given in the text is $\binom{8}{3} \binom{7}{3} + \binom{8}{4} \binom{7}{2} = 3430$. I understand this line of thinking--first count all the ways we can choose $3$ of the $8$ women and $3$ of the $7$ men. Then, add to this all of the we can choose $4$ of the $8$ women and $2$ of the $7$ men.

I thought about this question a bit differently, however, and am failing to see where my line of thinking is flawed. This is how I performed the calculation:

$$\binom{8}{3} \binom{7}{2} 10 = 11760$$

In other words, we choose $3$ women and then $2$ men. Then, we are left with $10$ other choices, the gender of whom is irrelevant. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting things too many times: If the sixth member is a female, then you get a committee of $4$ women and $2$ men, but exactly this committee was chosen $3$ other times. If the sixth member is a man then this $3$ women / $3$ men committee was chosen $2$ other times.

Note that you can thus fix your reasoning to compute:
$$\binom{8}{3}\binom{7}{2}\left(\frac{5}{4}+\frac{5}{3}\right)=3430.$$

Comment: I see it now. To be more clear, if the sixth choice (from the last choice of ten) was a female, I would have a subcommittee of four females. However, this same subcommittee of females is counted four times--once where each of the four is counted as the "last" choice, and the other three are chosen in the "first" $\binom{8}{3}$ choice.

Comment: @BrennonBortz: Exactly.

Comment: @BrennonBortz, I've edited to add a computation along the lines of your idea.